# Can't publish version to npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, publishing

Trying to update my npm package. Both [the npm website](https://www.npmjs.org/package/humanize-duration) and [`npm info`](https://gist.github.com/EvanHahn/bde5cd4379b7ac57cc42) say that I'm at version 0.6.1.

But when I bump the version to 0.7.0, I get a "cannot publish over existing version" error:

```
npm ERR! publish fail Cannot publish over existing version.
npm ERR! publish fail Update the 'version' field in package.json and try again.
npm ERR! publish fail
npm ERR! publish fail If the previous version was published in error, see:
npm ERR! publish fail     npm help unpublish
npm ERR! publish fail
npm ERR! publish fail To automatically increment version numbers, see:
npm ERR! publish fail     npm help version

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "publish" "."
npm ERR! cwd /Users/evanhahn/HumanizeDuration.js
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.21
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! code EPUBLISHCONFLICT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/evanhahn/HumanizeDuration.js/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I've never pushed 0.7.0.

I also tried pushing 0.7.1 and it gave the same error.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you add your package.json?

Comment: I ran into one issue like this which was fixed by upgrading to the latest node release. (If you wonder whether it was just some sort of transient network issue, the answer is no: this was really a bug that was fixable by upgrading.)

Comment: Got the same issue today and it was resolved by update the npm

    npm install npm -g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to the latest `npm` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Can't see or publish packages with Verdaccio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64918543/cant-see-or-publish-packages-with-verdaccio/68940481#68940481)

if it's not working to update npm

--> try this,

if you don't have the same package on the registry and your local package
it makes you conflict cuz they are not the same or no existing package

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.