# Can't see or publish packages with Verdaccio

Tags: verdaccio

I’m fairly new to Verdaccio. Been familiar with the tool for quite some time, but this is my first time trying to use it. I’ve installed it locally for the purpose of trying to figure out the right syntax for handling versioning, tagging and publishing a shared component library for work, but I’m having trouble getting this package published to my locally running instance of Verdaccio, and I’m struggling to understand why the publish command is failing. Was hoping someone here might be able to help.

First off, I should say that I have it installed and running locally, I can browse to http://localhost:7890 and see the Verdaccio web UI, and it says that I have “No package published yet.” That makes sense, because I haven’t been able to successfully publish anything yet. I’ve created a user with the `npm adduser —registry http://localhost:7890` command, and then after that I ran the following command to attempt to publish to it: `npm publish —access public —registry http://localhost:7890`. When I run this command, I get the following error: “EPUBLISHCONFLICT … Cannot publish over existing version.”

Now, I can in fact see, when I look in `.local/share/verdaccio/storage` that there is a folder for the scope that I published with, and in that folder, there is a folder for the package that I apparently published, and it only has a `package.json` file in it. I’ve attempted to wipe this all clean, reinstall Verdaccio, etc, etc, nothing seems to fix the issue. I can’t seem to make this package go away, *OR* to get it to display in the UI either. After publishing (unsuccessfully), and despite the face that it says this version of the package exists, I still see nothing in the UI. It still just says “No package published yet”, which I still don’t really understand.

Any ideas would be appreciated. This has me pretty stumped. Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to publish an existing package with the same version that exist on npmjs?

Answer (score 0):

Add your package.json name as npm registry (it needs the same one you published the last time).

I was getting this issue:

[image: The error coming out the npm publish]

The following works for me:

```
npm publish  --registry=http://yourhost:yourport
```